# How do I link a library in VSCode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, libraries, curses

I'm trying to include curses.h and some functions from that lib (specifically detecting a keyboard hit without stopping), but whenever I try, it gives the error "symbols not found." I'm assuming that this is because the clang++ compiler sees curses.h as a C library. I've gathered I need to link curses.h, but I don't know how and I could not find any real guides.

I'm writing a program in C++ using VSCode and clang++ on a mac. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to add the ncurses lib in ```tasks.json``` file. Also, you don't *link* a curses.h file, you link a library. Or do you mean that the compiler doesn't find curses.h?

Comment: This should help: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac)

Comment: @Roy2511 I'll try messing around with the tasks.json. And yes, the compiler's not finding curses.h.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who has this problem- my clang version was outdated. It was installed, so after a brief check, I thought all was good. However, it was not able to compile (nor find some libs for some reason) the newer versions of C++. Installing the latest version of clang fixed all issues.